# purpose of [mv setRegion:region animated:yes];

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I'm a beginner for IOS development. So wish someone could explain it with some details. The method is for viewforannotation.

If I keep

```
[mv setRegion:region animated:yes]
```

at the end of the function then the code will be in a infinite loop somehow, when I zoom in the map.

If I remove it, the mapview works perfectly fine.

Since I did not write the code, I do not see the purpose of using the line. Could someone tell me is that line necessary?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation {

 UIButton *abutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
 [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:abutton];

 MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 8000, 8000);
 [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

 return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code where you implemented it?

Comment: The code is added. Thanks.

Comment: Craig's answer is correct.  That line doesn't belong there.  You haven't posted the whole code so it's not clear why the original writer put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not edit the map's location within viewforannotation. viewForAnnotation is called when the map needs to draw the annotations on the map, if while doing that you change the part of the map that the MKMapView is moved there will be different annotations to be drawn, so from within viewForAnnotation you're making it call viewForAnnotation again ==> infinite loop.

So if like you say the code works fine without it, then remove it and be happy. That's my advice for any code. If the application works without it, remove it. No point in bulking up your application with unnecessary code.

Comment: the function is  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
which uses viewForAnnotation, and has the line at the very end. Is that what you mean? I found out the difference, which is it will adjust the map to fit in a specific region. However, when I zoom in the region, the map will stop and program will get in this infinite loop.

Comment: You should not change the region that the map is looking at in that function. You should *only* create and return the view for the annotation that iOS is asking for. Moving the the map while it is asking you to draw the annotations is definitely a bad idea.